# Linux kernel not reporting duplicates

Tags: linux, input, report, duplicates, sample

I have created a driver for a proximity sensor that returns ADC count to the userspace. The userspace then converts the ADC to the distance. The problem is, sometimes the ADC value is not stable - the light condition changes, or something else. When I want to resample the data in the userspace library, it may happen that the next data is same and the Linux kernel does not report it, making it not possible for me to report accurate distance.

What should I do in this case? Is there a way to allow Linux kernel to report these duplicates so my sampling code works? Should I modify the input reporting code?

I cannot move the ADC conversion to kernel side, as the conversion itself requires some maths and floating points.

The code that removes the duplicates is in the drivers/input/input.c input_handle_abs_event function.

More to say, the device is running Android and the proximity sensor is APS-12D.

Comment: How do you know the sample is a duplicate?  Because it is the same ADC value as the previous?  If so, I would just discard the duplicate in the driver, or have a minimum sample period to return a duplicate value, which still could be a unique conversion which just happens to be the same as the previous sample.

Comment: @PeterL. My driver code is not removing the duplicate, it's the Linux input subsystem that does it. I would like to be able to send it always.

Comment: Not sure how the subsystem would remove a sample and lose it.  Perhaps if you post some code we could take a look.